# SQL Server login failed" (Error 18456) Suddenly

Tags: sql-server

This morning we suddenly can't connect to our sql server 2008 developer edition. I have try with both of Windows Integration mode and SQL Authentication mode. Both are failed. It complained the error:  "Login failed for user ''. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)". I'm sure that it works well with the same usernames before. I haven't do any broken changes on the operating system or sql server before. I can't find any useful clue from Windows Events. In the article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx, it said that we may have more details from the sql server log. But, now, I even log into the server. Do you have any idea? 
Thanks.

Leo

Comment: Error log is a text file, can be opened with notepad or similar. You can find it at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log" (it's path to log for default instance on my laptop).

Comment: Could it be that you need to change password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login failed for user (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:18456) SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760919/login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error18456-sql-server-2005)