# SQL Server Login failed for user after a couple hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

I've been struggling with this problem for a while. When I tried to connect to my database I'm getting the error 18456: "Login failed for user ". I've checked all my settings and everything seems to be fine. If I access to the server via Windows Authentication there's no problem and I can reset the password of my user, and everything works again just for a couple hours and then I'm getting the same error again.

Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Is the account getting locked out after too many incorrect login attempts?

Comment: No, even if there's not even a single connection attempt during that time throws the Login failed error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation and found the reason as missing "SQL Server authentication mode" enabled. Maybe you can try the [answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689201/4684232)

Answer (score -1):

The reason behind the error is hidden as to improve security. In an SQL server error log there should be an error state. If you go to this [site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366351(v=sql.105).aspx) there is a table with what your problem is. The info is here anyway:

state 2: User ID is not valid.

state 5: User ID is not valid.

state 6: An attempt was made to use a Windows login name with SQL Server Authentication.

state 7: Login is disabled, and the password is incorrect.

state 8: The password is incorrect.

state 9: Password is not valid.

state 11: Login is valid, but server access failed.

state 12: Login is valid login, but server access failed.

state 18: Password must be changed.

Comment: Please copy the relevant information from behind the link into the answer.  In ten years this question may still be relevant, but the link will likely be broken.